# Error parsing Optional<T> with Jackson / Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, optional-parameters

I have a class and would prefer to have the values `Optional<T>` such as `Optional<Integer> value;`.

In this project `Springboot` is used to create web controllers and the clients send / receive via `json`.

When the client puts or posts, and the parsing class in `java` has `Optional<T>` type parameters, it fails; otherwise it works fine.  However; `Optional<T>` is preferred because we want to give the client the ability to omit fields if they aren't used.

**For example:**

**This works:**

```
public class TestClass {

    private final int testValue;

    public TestClass(@JsonProperty("testValue") int testValue) {
        this.testValue = testValue;
    }

    public int getTestValue() {
        return testValue;
    }
}
```

**This doesn't:**

```
public class TestClass {

    private final Optional<Integer> testValue;

    public TestClass(@JsonProperty("testValue") Optional<Integer> testValue) {
        this.testValue = testValue;
    }

    public Optional<Integer> getTestValue() {
        return testValue;
    }
}
```

Here are some version lines from Gradle.

```
springBootVersion = '1.5.8.RELEASE'
```

---

```
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-xml', version: '2.6.4'
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jdk8', version: '2.6.3'
```

When POSTing with Postman and the value is an `int` things work.  When I use `Optional<Integer>` I get the following error response from the web call.

**Summarized:**

> "exception":
>   "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
>   "message": "JSON parse error: 0; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: 0 (through
>   reference chain:
>   …(my class path)… [\"actions\"]->java.util.ArrayList[3])",

Comment: Please provide the spring-boot version and the error message/stacktrace.

Comment: @m4gic  Thank you, I've updated the question with those provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing any existing code upgrading Jackson to version `2.8.6` fixed it.

I did follow another answer above, strangely, upgrading to a higher version of `2.9.6' did not work. It did however give me a new error message that lead me eventually to a thread where other folks also had to downgrade also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change second example to

```
public TestClass(@JsonProperty("testValue") int testValue) {
    this.testValue = Optional.of(testValue);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is testValue will always be zero and never null.  I want it to be null if they don't supply a value.

Comment: @Michael Puckett II Looking at your question, I would say, you want an empty `Optional` in case the integer is `null`, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

There's a Jackson module that helps serialize/deserialize `Optional` parameters.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
   <version>2.9.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Then register the module with your `ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
```

Example here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-optional

Answer (score 0):

java.util.Optional is not serializable

Answer (score 0):

Optional means it is not necessarily have the object you looking for! So you can simply use a wrapper. You can return the object (if object is present)  or you can return a 404 status if your object is not present.

```
public static <X> ResponseEntity<X> wrapOrNotFound(Optional<X> maybeResponse, HttpHeaders header) {
    return maybeResponse.map(response -> ResponseEntity.ok().headers(header).body(response))
            .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
}
```

Comment: Sort of.  What I want is for the client to be able to submit the json with fields omitted.  If they are then we null the left over values.